# SSL in Node 8 vs Node 7

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a scenario  using HTTPS with this snippet as a server:

```
// (NodeJS)
import * as https from "https";

this.server = https.createServer({
  cert: this.cert, key: this.privKey, requestCert: true,
}, (request, response) => {
    ...
}
```

With version `Node 7.10.1`, I can connect using `Java 1.8.0_131 64 bit`, offering a client certificate.

But if I upgrade to `Node 8.7.0`, the only way I can use that snippet is changing `requestCert` to false. Otherwise, the Java code throws an exception:

> Remote host closed connection during handshake during web service communication

Is there any breaking difference between Node 7 and Node 8 in terms of TLS (SSL)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues going on in node side since 8.5.0 onward in regards to SSL in general, till there are fixed I suggest to downgrade to node 8.5.0 or below.